# Slurm script for parallel execution of independent tasks not working

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm, hpc, openfoam

I am having a problem with the Slurm script as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=parReconstructPar        # Job name
#SBATCH --output=log.parReconstructPar      # Standard output and error log
#SBATCH --partition=orbit                   # define the partition
#SBATCH -n 32
#

srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 0.0:0.3 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 0.35:0.65 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 0.7:1.0 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 1.05:1.35 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 1.4:1.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 1.75:2.05 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 2.1:2.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 2.45:2.75 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 2.8:3.1 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 3.15:3.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 3.45:3.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 3.75:4.0 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.05:4.3 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.35:4.6 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.65:4.9 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.95:5.2 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 5.25:5.5 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 5.55:5.8 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 5.85:6.1 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 6.15:6.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 6.45:6.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 6.75:7.0 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.05:7.3 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.35:7.6 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.65:7.9 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.95:8.2 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 8.25:8.5 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 8.55:8.8 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 8.85:9.1 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 9.15:9.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 9.45:9.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 9.75:10.0 &
```

The script is supposed to submit several tasks that are independent from each other and should run in parallel. However, when submitting the job to the scheduler, the tasks aren't launched and the job is removed immediately. The log file does not show a single entry.

If someone could tell me, what is wrong with this, that would be very appreciated.

Best regards

I tried running the script without --exclusive and also with explicit memory allocation.

Comment: This seems to be a question that should be asked on the helpdesk of the used HPC system. Each such system has different rules for submitting jobs (for example, isn't some project allocation required to define a job?).

Comment: Thank you for your help, the cluster is our own, so there is no helpdesk I could contact. However, I just found this:
https://hpc.nmsu.edu/discovery/slurm/serial-parallel-jobs/
When I follow their section on parallel jobs, it is working. So I think I had to assign the additional flags and also the command "wait" at the end was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the command `wait` at the end of the submission script. Without `wait` to wait for all the backgrounded processes to complete, the script will exit straight away as you have seen.

i.e. Your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=parReconstructPar        # Job name
#SBATCH --output=log.parReconstructPar      # Standard output and error log
#SBATCH --partition=orbit                   # define the partition
#SBATCH -n 32
#

srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 0.0:0.3 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 0.35:0.65 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 0.7:1.0 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 1.05:1.35 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 1.4:1.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 1.75:2.05 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 2.1:2.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 2.45:2.75 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 2.8:3.1 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 3.15:3.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 3.45:3.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 3.75:4.0 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.05:4.3 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.35:4.6 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.65:4.9 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 4.95:5.2 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 5.25:5.5 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 5.55:5.8 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 5.85:6.1 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 6.15:6.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 6.45:6.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 6.75:7.0 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.05:7.3 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.35:7.6 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.65:7.9 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 7.95:8.2 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 8.25:8.5 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 8.55:8.8 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 8.85:9.1 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 9.15:9.4 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 9.45:9.7 &
srun --exclusive -n1 reconstructPar -allRegions -time 9.75:10.0 &


wait
```